# JDOQL: How to execute "CREATE USER"?

Tags: sql, datanucleus, jdoql

I'm trying to create a USER (in this case using a H2 database) using JDOQL in DataNucleus

```
PersistenceManager pm=pmf.getPersistenceManager();
Query query = pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL", "CREATE USER GUEST PASSWORD 'abc'");
query.execute();
```

result: **org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Method is only allowed for a query. Use execute or executeUpdate instead of executeQuery**;

How can i execute this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to set the pmf property?
datanucleus.query.sql.allowAll=true

Another way you can try is something like that:

```
JDOConnection con = pm.getDataStoreConnection();
Connection nativeCon = (Connection) con.getNativeConnection();
...
Statement stmt = nativeCon.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE USER GUEST PASSWORD 'abc'");
...
```

Comment: Yes, i have the "datanucleus.query.sql.allowAll=true". Your answer is the only option that could really work. Thanks.